# Export more than 1000 rows from Azure Synapse into csv

Tags: azure, csv, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

In Databricks you can export more than 1000 rows of a table by doing the following:

[image]

And downloading the full results.

On Azure Synapse, you get no such option to download the full results:

[image]

It defaults to exporting only the first 1000 rows. How can we download all rows of a table to a csv from Azure Synapse without writing more code? I checked and downloading to json is also only 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By default** the `display()` in Pyspark shows the **first 1000 rows** only. In databricks it is possible to download more than 1000 rows with display() by **re-executing** it.

[image]

Unfortunately, **synapse notebook does not have that feature now**. You can raise a feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9b9ba8e4-0825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8).

> How can we download all rows of a table to a csv from Azure Synapse
> **without writing more code**?

When we have a limitation like that, we have to do it by code only.

Save the dataframe to blob storage as csv with the help of Blob linked service and download it.

```
import pandas

pandas_data= df.toPandas()
pandas_data.to_csv("abfss://<container-name>/filename.csv",storage_options = {'linked_service' :    '<linkedsservicename>'})
```

[image]

The above code is referred from this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/newbe-exporting-full-result-from-azure-synapse-notebook-cell/m-p/3072014) by **FrancisRomstad**.